# How do I install ejabberd 14.05 in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-10.04, ejabberd

I want to install latest **ejabberd 14.05**, XMPP server in Ubuntu 10.04.

when i run command

```
apt-get -y install ejabberd
```

it installed ejabberd 2.1.2 but I'd like the latest one to be installed.

How do I get the latest ejabberd version installed? If it's not possible, then due to what reasons exactly?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You're just asking how to use apt-get. An appropriate question for SO would be, "I'm adding a new module to ejabberd 14.05 <code excerpt> and it's not getting called when a user sends a message. What's wrong?"

Comment: did you install?I am facing a similar issue.Cant we do it like this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpJabberServer

Answer (score 0):

To install latest ejabberd on Ubuntu, you should check [ejabberd Download page](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads). It offers different packaging, either binary installer or `.deb` package files.